# dynamic combo box with dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, php

I'm having a problem with my `combobox` and dynamic fields. So basically, I input data in to a `mysql table` from a for witch has dynamic rows. Each row has 2 comboboxes the second depended on the first. On the first row everything works ok but when I add more rows the second combobox fails to show the records.

This is my code:

```html
                            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>ID</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div>Klienti</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div>Produkti</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div>Njesia</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div>MAC</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div>Sasisa</div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div></div>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input size="1" type="text" name="id[]" value="<?php echo "$modulid";?>" class="form-control name_list" readonly /></td>
                                <td><input size="1" type="text" name="klienti[]" value="<?php echo "$emriklientit";?>" class="form-control name_list" readonly /></td>
                                <td>
                                <div>
                                <div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-75">
                                <select id="name" name="name[]" class="form-control name_list" required >
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="A">A</option>
                                <option value="B">B</option>    
                                <option value="C">C</option>
                                <option value="D">D</option>
                                </select>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                <div>
                                <div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-75">
                                <select id="njesia" name="njesia[]" class="form-control name_list" required >     
                                </select>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                </td>

                                <td><input  type="text" name="mac[]" placeholder="00:11:22:33:44:55" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                                <td><input size="2" type="text" name="sasia[]" placeholder="Sasia" class="form-control name_list" /></td>

                                <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Shto</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    var i=1;
    $('#add').click(function(){
        i++;
        $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="id[]" size="1" value="<?php echo "$modulid";?>" class="form-control name_list" readonly /></td><td><input size="1" type="text" name="klienti[]" value="<?php echo "$emriklientit";?>" class="form-control name_list" readonly /></td><td><div><div></div><div class="col-75"><select id="name" name="name[]" class="form-control name_list" required ><option value=""></option><option value="A">A</option><option value="B">B</option> <option value="C">C</option><option value="D">D</option></select></div></div></td><td><div><div></div><div class="col-75"><select id="njesia" name="njesia[]" class="form-control name_list" required ></select></div></div></td><td><input  type="text" name="mac[]" placeholder="00:11:22:33:44:55" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><input type="text" size="2" name="sasia[]" placeholder="Sasia" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
        $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
    }); 
});

    $("#name").change(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val == "A") {
        $("#njesia").html("<option value=''></option><option value='A1'>A1</option><option value='B1'>B1</option>");
    } else if (val == "B") {
        $("#njesia").html("<option value=''></option><option value='A2'>A2</option><option value='B2'>B2</option>");
    }else if (val == "C") {
        $("#njesia").html("<option value=''></option><option value='A3'>A3</option><option value='B3'>B3</option>");
    }
});
```

Comment: The new elements (select menus) you add have duplicate IDs and of course will not work correctly

Comment: how do you sugest i fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly let me say that I don't use `jQuery` so what follows is a bad hybridisation of vanilla js and jQuery ~ no doubt it can be achieved with only jQuery!

In the original HTML table modify this to remove the ID and add an inline ( yes, I know ) event handler to the initial `select` menu.

```
<td>
    <div>
        <div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-75">
            <select name="name[]" class="form-control name_list" required onchange="setoptions(event)">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="B">B</option>
                <option value="C">C</option>
                <option value="D">D</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>

<td>
    <div>
        <div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-75">
            <select name="njesia[]" class="form-control name_list" required>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Within the inserted HTML string in the javascript function do likewise and remove the ID and add the inline event handler ( yes, I know )

```
<select name="name[]" class="form-control name_list" required onchange="setoptions(event)">
```

and also

```
<select name="njesia[]" class="form-control name_list" required>
```

And if you define the `findparent` and `setoptions` functions like so:

```
function findparent(n){
    while( n.tagName!='TD' ){
        n=n.parentNode;
    }
    return n
}
function setoptions(event){
    var oCell=findparent( event.target );
    var oSelect=oCell.parentNode.querySelector('select[name="njesia[]"]');

    var html;

    switch( event.target.value ){
        case 'A':html="<option value=''></option><option value='A1'>A1</option><option value='B1'>B1</option>";break;
        case 'B':html="<option value=''></option><option value='A2'>A2</option><option value='B2'>B2</option>";break;
        case 'C':html="<option value=''></option><option value='A3'>A3</option><option value='B3'>B3</option>";break;
        case 'D':html="<option value=''></option><option value='A4'>A4</option><option value='B4'>B4</option>";break;
    }

    oSelect.innerHTML='';
    oSelect.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',html)
}
```

You should find then that the `chained` dropdown menu is targeted correctly because of the parent/sibling selectors

```js
function findparent(n){
  while( n.tagName!='TD' ){
    n=n.parentNode;
  }
  return n
}
function setoptions(event){
  var oCell=findparent( event.target );
  var oSelect=oCell.parentNode.querySelector('select[name="njesia[]"]');

  var html;

  switch( event.target.value ){
    case 'A':html="<option value=''></option><option value='A1'>A1</option><option value='B1'>B1</option>";break;
    case 'B':html="<option value=''></option><option value='A2'>A2</option><option value='B2'>B2</option>";break;
    case 'C':html="<option value=''></option><option value='A3'>A3</option><option value='B3'>B3</option>";break;
    case 'D':html="<option value=''></option><option value='A4'>A4</option><option value='B4'>B4</option>";break;
  }

  oSelect.innerHTML='';
  oSelect.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',html)
}
  
$( document ).ready(function(){
  var i=1;

  $('#add').click(function(){
    i++;
    $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="id[]" size="1" value="" class="form-control name_list" readonly /></td><td><input size="1" type="text" name="klienti[]" value="" class="form-control name_list" readonly /></td><td><div><div></div><div class="col-75"><select name="name[]" class="form-control name_list" required onchange="setoptions(event)"><option value=""></option><option value="A">A</option><option value="B">B</option><option value="C">C</option><option value="D">D</option></select></div></div></td><td><div><div></div><div class="col-75"><select name="njesia[]" class="form-control name_list" required></select></div></div></td><td><input  type="text" name="mac[]" placeholder="00:11:22:33:44:55" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><input type="text" size="2" name="sasia[]" placeholder="Sasia" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
  });
      $( document ).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(e){
        var n=e.target;
        while( n.tagName!='TR' )n=n.parentNode;
        n.parentNode.removeChild( n );
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>ID</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div>Klienti</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div>Produkti</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div>Njesia</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div>MAC</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div>Sasisa</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input size="1" type="text" name="id[]" value="<?php echo " $modulid ";?>" class="form-control name_list" readonly />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input size="1" type="text" name="klienti[]" value="<?php echo " $emriklientit ";?>" class="form-control name_list" readonly />
        </td>
        <td>
          <div>
            <div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <select name="name[]" class="form-control name_list" required onchange="setoptions(event)">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="B">B</option>
                <option value="C">C</option>
                <option value="D">D</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>

        <td>
          <div>
            <div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-75">
              <select name="njesia[]" class="form-control name_list" required></select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="text" name="mac[]" placeholder="00:11:22:33:44:55" class="form-control name_list" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input size="2" type="text" name="sasia[]" placeholder="Sasia" class="form-control name_list" />
        </td>

        <td>
          <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Shto</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: this works perfectly well for the dropdown menu but when i submit to save to database only the first row is stored

Comment: you need to inspect the FORM data in PHP when it is posted. Is there a single field or lots? As there is no PHP here it is hard to tell

Comment: im dumd your code is perfectly fine everythink works. everythink is stored ok i forgot to add id when displaying the data and it was only showing parts of it

Comment: Good news - was just testing in php to see what was happening. Good luck!